# Managing giant eBook collection with iPad after iTunes update broke compatibility with Calibre?

Tags: itunes, ipad, books, ebook

In an effort to upgrade security, a recent iTunes update broke functionality to Calibre - my favorite eBook management tool. Now I am without a way to effectively manage my eBook collection in a organized fashion between my iTunes library and my iPad. I find that although iTunes handles music well, it doesn't manage eBook libraries very well at all.

[Here is message board post](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2113958&postcount=3) describing the iTunes security update.

Does anyone know how I can manage my eBook collection so I can keep track of what I have on my iPad and easily sync and manage my hundreds of books?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when iBooks got updated. The way I access Calibre when on my iPad is to put my Calibre library in Dropbox. Then, I can just access ebooks in Dropbox and 'Open With…' iBooks, read them, and delete them again. I used to do the same thing but using the CrashPlan app; either would work (it basically depends on what cloud storage system you have the most space with).

It's inelegant, but there's no more elegant way that I can think of.